# Volume of a Parallelepiped, Vectors

Tags: vectors, volume

I have designed three vectors that consist of:
\begin{align}
a &= -4i-10j-k\\
b &= 7i+9j-2k\\
c &= 3i+9j+4k\\
\end{align}
And the task was to find the volume that was created from the above vectors when creating a parallelepiped. The current method I have used is modulus matrix of the scalar triple product ($a$.$b*c$) and also the distributive law. the results concluded from this was $88$ units cubed, but I was wondering whether there were any other methods I could use to verify my answer?

Comment: See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Volume

Comment: I feel that you have used all methods available, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V=|-4\cdot9\cdot4+(-1)\cdot7\cdot9+3\cdot(-10)\cdot(-2)-3\cdot9\cdot(-1)-(-4)\cdot9\cdot(-2)-4\cdot7\cdot(-10)|=88$$
It's the best way, I think.

We can also just to prove this formula.

Id est, let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be our parallelepiped.

We can find $S_{ABCD}=AB\cdot AC\cdot\sin\measuredangle BAC$ and calculate an altitude $A'K$ to $ABCD$ of the parallelepiped.

By this way we calculate a module of the scalar triple product of our vectors.

Comment: What method did you use at the beginning @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @Carlos Bray  Yes, but I did not see it before. By the way, you can use the second way, but it's just the same.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that is the best and easiest way of finding the volume of a parallelepiped. The area of the base is given by $b*c$. multiplying that by its height, $a$, we get the volume.
Although, I suppose the product of the moduli of each vector might be an idea. I'm not quite sure.

Comment: The product of the vector moduli generally gives the wrong answer, as it does in this case.

Comment: thanks @JohnHughes